# Problem with Canonical partners repository?

Tags: installation, 12.10, repository, canonical, adobe-reader

I enabled the canonical partners repository but I can't install Acrobat reader (acroread).  I've found only a few programs in Ubuntu Software Center in the Canonical Partners section. Is this bug due to something I did or something else?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit). I solved it by enabling the following PPA and installing the version of acroread that it provided:
https://launchpad.net/~portis25/+archive/multiarch

As of right now, it does not appear to be available in Canonical Partners:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread